# Printing specific columns from pandas dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas dataframe looks like this. How do I get the output where the STATE is closed and display the ForeignAddr and ForeignPort

I tried the following and it only gives the IP.
`print(dfNetscan[(dfNetscan.State == 'CLOSED')]["ForeignAddr"].values[0])`

When I try adding the port as
`dfNetscan[(dfNetscan.State == 'CLOSED')]["ForeignAddr"]["ForeignPort"].values[0]` it errors out.

```
        TreeDepth          Offset  Proto   LocalAddr  LocalPort    ForeignAddr  ForeignPort        State   PID         Owner                      Created
0           0  0xac818d494050  UDPv4     0.0.0.0          0              *            0          NaN   776     lsass.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000
1           0  0xac818d494050  UDPv6          ::          0              *            0          NaN   776     lsass.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:03.000000
2           0  0xac818db931a0  TCPv4     0.0.0.0        135        0.0.0.0            0    LISTENING   496   svchost.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000
3           0  0xac818db931a0  TCPv6          ::        135             ::            0    LISTENING   496   svchost.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000
4           0  0xac818db932f0  TCPv4     0.0.0.0      49664        0.0.0.0            0    LISTENING   632   wininit.exe  2021-04-01 05:05:02.000000
..        ...             ...    ...         ...        ...            ...          ...          ...   ...           ...                          ...
74          0  0xac8192d4c910  TCPv4  10.1.1.182      52871  13.75.160.154          443     SYN_SENT  2992   MsMpEng.exe  2021-04-06 01:56:51.000000
75          0  0xac8192f10ba0  TCPv4  10.1.1.182      52868  184.85.82.103           80       CLOSED   652   svchost.exe  2021-04-06 01:56:38.000000
76          0  0xac81949e9930  TCPv4  10.1.1.182      52763    13.54.35.87         5555  ESTABLISHED    32  PSclient.exe  2021-04-06 01:02:26.000000
77          0  0xac81959954a0  TCPv4  10.1.1.182       3389     10.2.0.196        56343  ESTABLISHED  1092   svchost.exe  2021-04-06 01:55:11.000000
78          0  0xac81959ebb80  TCPv4  10.1.1.182       5985     10.1.1.110        63743  ESTABLISHED     4        System  2021-04-06 01:02:25.000000
```

Comment: `dfNetscan.loc[dfNetscan.State == 'CLOSED', ["ForeignAddr", "ForeignPort"]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
dfNetscan[(dfNetscan.State == 'CLOSED')][["ForeignAddr","ForeignPort"]].values[0]
```